# How to overlay GeoJSON on OSM with OpenLayers?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, geo, openstreetmap

I am trying to create one map. I am using OSM as base layer and now I am trying to overlay my road network as GeoJSON. There is no error in my code (Checked by Firebug). I can view nice map of OSM but problem is there is not any road network on my OSM map. I do not know what I have done worng. Bellow, I have given my code.

I used following command to create GeoJSON from my console. I am using OSGeo Live (Ubuntu).

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" roads.json roads.shp roads
```

JavaScript Code----

```
//OSM Layer-----------------------------------------------
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");
map.addLayer(layer);

//GeoJSON Layer-------------------------------------------
var vector_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({}); 
var vector_protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: 'ml/roads.json',
    format: vector_format
});
var vector_strategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()];
var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('More Advanced Vector Layer',{
    protocol: vector_protocol,
    strategies: vector_strategies 
});

map.addLayer(vector_layer);

//Projection-----------------------------------------------
map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(18.068611, 59.329444).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 10
);
```

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you may try to set visibility to the layer once added to the map using `layer.setVisibility(true)`

Second you should look using firebug if the request to `ml/road.json` is done and that you got data for the part of the map you're looking.

Then you may want to refresh the layer, here is what I used in a pas project :
`layer.refresh({force:true});`

Finally you may try putting the layers directly in the Map constructor :

```
//OSM Layer-----------------------------------------------
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");

//GeoJSON Layer-------------------------------------------
var vector_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({}); 
var vector_protocol = new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: 'ml/roads.json',
    format: vector_format
});
var vector_strategies = [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()];
var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('More Advanced Vector Layer',{
    protocol: vector_protocol,
    strategies: vector_strategies,
    isBaseLayer: false
});

var options = {
    layers: [layer, vector_layer]
};
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("Map", options);
//Projection-----------------------------------------------
map.setCenter(
    new OpenLayers.LonLat(18.068611, 59.329444).transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
    ), 10
);
```

Comment: I checked my firebug console. It shows GET http://localhost/ml/roads.json 200 OK 116ms. It seems my json file load just fine. And secondly I tried with your solution. But it creates two map. Top one is blank white map and bottom one is OSM map. There is no overlay sign.

Comment: @Shahjalal Sorry there was a bit too much copy/paste, I corrected the code. You may want to try it out.

Comment: it is really strange, your code is not working with me. Is there any other way? Is there anything wrong in my GeoJSON data? But, I did not create anything by hand, as i said above. Should I use bounding Bounding Box? I got one example from [link](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/all-overlays.html). I am trying to do almost the same. But problem is, i do not know how to put my bounding box values. Is it possible to generate these values from GeoJSON data? If so, then, how? I tried with above example, it does not work without Bounding Box(data/roads.json);

Answer (score 0):

Is your GeoJSON in `EPSG:900913`? You should try to set the projection of the map explicitely in your map constructor.

Comment: I tried. But problem is, if I use EPSG:900913, then my map set the center somewhere in South Atlantic. But, I gave the coordinate of Stockholm. Actually, I got this projection (EPSG:4326) from one Openlayers example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/fusiontables.js. If you have any other specific help. Please give me. But, anyway, thanks for your try.

Comment: Which projection is your GeoJSON in? The projection transformation works with projection set in map , see http://tonio.biz/openlayers/examples/osm.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is one of projections.  You could use OGRINFO to get data about the roads.shp file but probably the easiest for what it sounds like you are doing is to make OGR2OGR use the Spherical Mercator projection.  You would do this by running OGR2OGR with the -t switch.  This should look like

```
$ ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" roads.json roads.shp roads -t_srs EPSG:900913
```

Then make sure your map is using the Spherical Mercator projection

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', 
            {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
                sphericalMercator: true });
```

This is probably the easiest way to integrate everything with OSM using the same GCS, EPSG900913 and EPSG:3857 should be synonymous.